a grid problem in which it is necessary to show that there are some columns that satisfy the requirement
Let n > 3 be a positive integer and a 50 × n grid (50 rows and n columns). People fill in the numbers 1 and −1
unit squares of the table (each cell contains exactly 1 number) so that the sum of the numbers in each row is positive. Proof
Prove that it is always possible to choose five columns of the table so that in each row, there is at least one unit square
One of the five selected columns contains the number 1.
I have the main idea of ​​using induction. If the problem is correct with n=2m-1, then when we consider a table with n=2m, the sum of the numbers in a row must definitely be greater than 1, so when we If we remove a certain column, we will get a table with n=2m-1 and the sum of all rows is positive, then it is correct according to the induction hypothesis. But what I'm having trouble with is what about the case n=2m+1, because then the total could be 1 and removing 1 column could lead to a row with a total of 0?
I also have another direction which is to contradict and show that there exists a row with the number of cells -1 on that row >= n/2, leads to absurdity, but to be honest, I don't think it's a good way and has a purely combinatorial touch, but more algebraic (I'll post this solution later). I want to help, thank you very much

In order to find a counterexample, if $n= 11$, you have five $-1$ per row in the worst case. You need to place them such that for any to set of five columns, there is a row which contains five $-1$. How many rows will you need to block all the possible sets of $5$ columns? If now $n=13$, you have six $-1$ per row available. How many rows will you need to block all the possible sets of $5$ columns?

@caduk Maybe I should watch it again

Maybe I was unclear, but I don't mean you will find a counterexample to your problem. I advise you to search for each $n$ how many rows you need to block all the set of $5$ columns. You should find that you will always need more than $50$ rows, thus proving that with less than $50$ rows, it is always possible to find such $5$ columns.

@caduk Actually, I was also thinking about this. I also found a blocker just now but it's not as good as yours. I will consider it.

What do you mean by a blocker? And by not as good as me?
For example, with $n=11$, a row can only block one set of $5$ columns (because we can only place five $-1$ per row) so we need at least $\binom{11}{5} = 462$ rows to block every set of $5$ columns. For $n=13$, you can place up to six $-1$ per row, so you can block more than one set of $5$ columns with only one row.  However,  you have more sets of $5$ columns to block. How many rows do you need in this scenario? How does it generalize?

@caduk Maybe we're not understanding each other, my English is very poor and google translate can't do its job correctly, I'm sorry but I need more time to think. :((
